# php load page without waiting for include to complete

Tags: php, include

My page consists of a simple form. When the user submits the form a process is instantly executed on the back-end that can take up to 5 minutes to complete.

This process is executed via an `include` of another php page. However, I do not want the user to have to wait 5 minutes for the page to refresh. Is there a way for the `include` to do its thing in the background and not require its completion for the remainder of the original page to load?

My current solution is to write the results of the form to the DB and then use a cronjob to check this table which then executes the code. This seems rather unnecessary to me. Is there a better way?

Thank you

Comment: You can use Ajax and show a message to the user to tell him to wait

Comment: Good point, except I don't want him to wait. I just want the page to load he doesn't need to know what's happening in the background.

Comment: What you need is a background process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process

Comment: Well, you can still use Ajax and don't display anything to the user. He won't notice the ajax call